# js UniteGallery

Tags: javascript

Подскажите может кто сталкивался в таким типом проблемы.
Я хочу на странице разместить JS UniteGallery, скачал готовый демо пример запустил его и все работает отлично, но если я подключаю jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

то галерея перестает работать, и выдаёт такую ошибку
`jQuery(...).unitegallery is not a function`
Насколько я понял галерея использует jquery-11.0.min.js и они конфликтуют между собой.

Страница:

1. Подключаемый "блок" top
2. Тело страницы
3. Подключаемый "блок" bot

В блоке топ подключена "обычная" jQuery.

На странице где галерея:

1. top
2. тело - здесь подключена jQuery галереи и другие необходимые ей js
3. bot

Получается на странице галереи подключена два jQuery "обычный" и от галереи. галерейный jQuery "обратносовместимый", а вот обычный к галереи не подходит.

Comment: jQuery подключен выше по коду.
сам jQuery подключен в блоке top.php, этот блок подключается выше 
unitegallery/js/jquery-11.0.min.js который нужен для галереи.

Comment: Если я подключаю jQuery от галереи все "кнопочки" с ним работают, но галерея не работает, а если подключаю на самой странице галереи jQuery, то галерея работает.

Comment: Страница:
Подключаемый "блок" top
Тело страницы
Подключаемый "блок" bot

В блоке топ подключена "обычная" jQuery.
На странице где галерея:
top
тело - здесь подключена jQuery галереи и другие необходимые ей js
bot
Получается на странице галереи подключена два jQuery "обычный" и от галереи. галерейный jQuery "обратносовместимый", а вот обычный к галереи не подходит.

Comment: Это похоже на компьютерный перевод на Алибаба. PHP преобразовывается в HTML и запишите в вопросе этот результирующий кусок HTML с местами ,где подключаются файлы. И что в каких случаях происходит.

Comment: Обновил сам вопрос там более читаемо.